# Kendo DateTimePicker does not have clock after read from local storage

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, local-storage, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**Scenario**
In my kendo Grid I have DateTime picker. Next, I save DateTime picker in local storage. When I go again to my page. There is only DatePicker (without clock).
I am a beginner with kendo. It is not my code so I am not sure if it is all.

**Code**

```
columns.Bound(p => p.CreateDate)
                    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(headerHtmlAttributes)
                    .Filterable(true)
                    .Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}").Filterable(f => f.UI("DateTimeFilter"));
```

And filter function

```
function DateTimeFilter(control) {
    $(control).kendoDateTimePicker({
        format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
    });
}
```

Save Function

```
    var saveGridOptions = function (eventFromGrid) {
    var grid = eventFromGrid.sender,
        gridId = $(grid.wrapper).attr('id');

    localStorage[gridId + gridStorageSuffix] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
};
```

Also have code when i create grid in cshtml file:

```
.Events(ev =>
{
    ev.DataBound("GridHelper.saveGridOptions");
    ev.ColumnResize("GridHelper.saveGridOptions");
    ev.ColumnHide("GridHelper.saveGridOptions");
    ev.ColumnShow("GridHelper.saveGridOptions");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Kendo UI MVC wrappers, it uses the standard ASP.Net MVC way of deciding
what editor template to use when editing a property.

The project editors normally reside in the projects Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.
Make sure you have included/copied all the editor templates provided by Telerik/Kendo.
(e.g. Integer.cshtml, Date.cshtml, DateTime.cshtml) into this folder.

You can also specify which editor to use manually by e.g.
1) Decorate you view model property with for e.g. 
    `[UIHint("DateTime")]` or
2) On the grid configuration, column row add 
    `.EditorTemplateName("DateTime")`

This should automatically then use the Kendo DateTime widget.

Comment: This problem happen only when I save it to local storage.